# STM32F207ZG USART CMSIS library

Tags: c, stm32, uart, usart, cmsis

I have a question about transmit data via USART on STM32 microcontroller. I use CMSIS library and try to sent string "Hello world" like it served in reference manual, But I spended many time and don't have results. My Terminal keep silent.
Below has my C language CMSIS code. Please point me Where I have the mistake in my code.

```
#include <stm32f207xx.h> //include lib
#include <stm32f2xx.h> //include lib

#define USART_Baud_Rate 9600 //define baud rate is 9600

    char string[] = "Hello World!\n"; //my string for send
    int send = 0; //integer variable

static void GPIO_Init(void);  //declaire function general-purpose input/output initilization
static void USART_Init(void); //declaire function USART input/output initilization

void USART3_Tx_Data(void); //Over here I`m daclare send string function

int main(void){
GPIO_Init();
USART_Init();
void delay(int i) { // delay function
  while (i-- > 0)
    asm("nop");
}

  while (1){
        delay(500000); 
        USART3_Tx_Data(); //Send string
  }

}

static void GPIO_Init(void){
    SET_BIT(RCC->AHB1ENR, RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIODEN); /* RCC CLOCK ENABLE FOR GPIOB */

}
static void USART_Init(void){
    SET_BIT(RCC->APB1ENR, RCC_APB1ENR_USART3EN);  /* RCC CLOCK ENABLE FOR USART */

    /* TX OUTPUT CONFIGURATION */

    /* PD9 IS 10 AS ALTERNATE FUNCTION MODE */
    CLEAR_BIT(GPIOD->MODER, GPIO_MODER_MODE9_0); 
    SET_BIT(GPIOD->MODER, GPIO_MODER_MODE9_1);

    /* OUTPUT PUSH-PULL */
    CLEAR_BIT(GPIOD->OTYPER, GPIO_OTYPER_OT_9);

    /* LOW SPEED FREQUENCY 2MHZ IS 00 (i tried different mode: middle, high, very high speed */
    CLEAR_BIT(GPIOD->OSPEEDR, GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEED9_0
            | GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEED9_1);

    /*SET BAUD RADE IS 9600 (i tried different SystemClock value, but on APB1 bus I have 30Mhz*/
    WRITE_REG(USART3->BRR, 30000000/USART_Baud_Rate); 

    /* USART CLOCK ENABLE and ENABLE TRANSMIT */
    SET_BIT(USART3->CR1, USART_CR1_UE    
             | USART_CR1_TE);                      
                                                                         
}
void USART3_Tx_Data(void){
    USART3->DR = string[send++]; // send string to DR (data register) 
    if((USART3->SR & USART_SR_TC) == USART_SR_TC{
        if(send == sizeof(string)) {
            send = 0;
            CLEAR_BIT(USART2->SR, USART_SR_TC); //Transmition is complite clear flag
        }
        else{
            USART3->DR = string[send++]; //Send next symbol 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your init function looks fine, but check if the baudrate calculation is correct. This is the calculation is in the Reference manual [calculation USART](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYwGk.png) (see page 643 of the "RM0033"). Under the calculation are also some examples.

I also see that you do not loop the string in the transmit function maybe it wil just send a character 500`000 ms. So it would only send a single character. Also check the TXE bit from the SR register. It also needs to be 1 even when sending a single character.